# Error: google is not defined using in Angular custom service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

There is the following custom Angular service:

```
angular.module('app.services', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps']).factory('Geocoder', ['$q', ($q) ->
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()

  geocode: (location) ->
    defer = $q.defer()
    geocoder.geocode { location: location }, (results, status) ->
      if status is google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK
        defer.resolve(results[0].formatted_address)
      else
        defer.reject()
    defer.promise()
])
```

When I try to execute Geocoder.geocode(...) in some controller I get the error "google is not defined", but if I use 'google.maps.Geocoder' in controller it works good. My main module:

```
module = angular.module('app', ['app.controllers', 'app.directives',
  'app.services', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps', 'dndLists'])

module.config(['$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  '$httpProvider', 'uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider', ($locationProvider,
  $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider,
  uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) ->

    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure(
      key: 'MYKEY'
      libraries: 'places, geocoder'
      v: '3.17')

    $stateProvider.state('home'
      url: ''
      controller: 'HomeController'
      templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
    )

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise ($injector) ->
      $state = $injector.get('$state')
      $state.go('home')

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
])
```

As you can see I load Google Maps. What is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: can you show your html?

Comment: If the loading of google maps is async, that may be the reason for it. Who assigns a value to `google`?